# Install docker on CoreOS container

Tags: docker, coreos

As part of my build I need to produce a docker image so I need docker installed in my CoreOS docker container but I can't seem to apt-get install it (can't find docker-engine or docker.io); it does find `docker` which appears to be a python module that I can run.

How do I get docker on my container?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually CoreOS is intended to run docker instead of being docker container.

If you only need to produce docker image from your build container (and not mess up with privileged containers and many issues with docker-inside-docker), you can mount docker socket of the host to be able to create containers:

> docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...

Let's say using Ubuntu docker image you start a container, which will be able to create containers on the host docker daemon, but will look like you have docker-in-docker:

```
docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ubuntu:latest sh -c "apt-get update ; apt-get install docker.io -y ; bash"
```

Now you are in the docker container, which "shares" docker space with the host:

```
root@01a656c6056a:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
01a656c6056a        ubuntu:16.04                                            "sh -c 'apt-get updat"   2 minutes ago      Up 2 minutes                                                        hungry_ardinghelli
```